# I am getting JSONResponse as "http:\/\/xyz.com\/xyz\/xyz" there are forward and backward slash in the response. how can i get it normal?

Tags: android, json, response

There are forward and backward slash in the response. how can i get it normal? I have tried using replaceall method. However i am still getting the same response url with backslash abd forward slash in it, If any one can help me with the same. Thank you in advance

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";



public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\/","/"); 
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String postAdUrl, String string,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BackGroundTask Task= new BackGroundTask(postAdUrl, string,  params);
    try {
        return Task.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }



}

public class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{
    List<NameValuePair> adparams= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String URL=null;
    String method = "POST";
public BackGroundTask(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        URL=url;
        adparams=params;
        this.method = method;
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
    // Making HTTP request 
        // check for request method

    if(method.equals("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(adparams));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(adparams, "utf-8");
            URL += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\` is a special character for both Java literals and regular expressions, so you'll have to escape it twice:

```
replaceAll("\\\\/","/");
```

Comment: thanks it worked like charm..!! Thanks a lot. :) I will upvote your answer right away..:)